# How to transform JSON message to valid JSON for avro schema with nullable fields?

Tags: java, json, regex, avro

I would like to send a JSON message to a kafka topic with avro-schema.

The avro-schema allows multiple types:

```
{  
   "name":"typeA",
   "type":[  
      "int",
      "null"
   ],
   "default":null
}
```

If the value is null, everything is fine. If the type is an `int` as in this case then this must be specified explicitly. See this ticket [AVRO-1582](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1582).

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "typeA":12345,
   "typeB":[
      {
         "feature":1,
         "value":"1"
      },
      {
         "feature":2,
         "value":"2"
      }
   ],
   "typeC":[
      {
         "a":12345,
         "data":[
            {
               "a":12345,
               "b":[
                  12345,
                  12345,
                  12345
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to transform into this JSON:

```
{
   "typeA":{
      "int":12345
   },
   "typeB":{
      "array":[
         {
            "feature":1,
            "value":"1"
         },
         {
            "feature":2,
            "value":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   "typeC":{
      "array":[
         {
            "a":12345,
            "data":[
               {
                  "a":12345,
                  "b":[
                     12345,
                     12345,
                     12345
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is is possible to transform `"typeA":12345` to `"typeA":{"int":12345}`? Exists an easy way to handle this issue?

I know the type of every field so I could use a regex in JAVA:

```
json.replaceAll("typeA\":([^,]*),\"", "typeA\":{\"int\":$1},\"");
```

It's hard to handle arrays or the last JSON element. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I like the old saying "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."  I am going to urge you to consider using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and create your json classes using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).  [Baeldung has lots of great tutorials on Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) if you need help.

Comment: @hooknc, I have a generated java class from avro schema. I generate JSON with Gson from my model. It is possible to overwrite the generation process with annotation on properties?

Answer (score 0):

I can transform `typeA` to:

```
"typeA":{
    "int":12345
},
```

But `typeB` and `typeC` were too difficult for me, because I couldn’t match it precisely. Somehow when I try to replace `typeB` with a array. Another place get replaced too, which we don’t want.

If you or someone else could solve that problem, then `typeC` can also be easily fixed. Because `typeB` and `typeC` are similar. I’m also curious what the solution is. So let me know!

I will now share how I fixed `typeA`. Here is the Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "{\r\n" +
                "   \"typeA\":12345,\r\n" +
                "   \"typeB\":[\r\n" +
                "      {\r\n" +
                "         \"feature\":1,\r\n" +
                "         \"value\":\"1\"\r\n" +
                "      },\r\n" +
                "      {\r\n" +
                "         \"feature\":2,\r\n" +
                "         \"value\":\"2\"\r\n" +
                "      }\r\n" +
                "   ],\r\n" +
                "   \"typeC\":[\r\n" +
                "      {\r\n" +
                "         \"a\":12345,\r\n" +
                "         \"data\":[\r\n" +
                "            {\r\n" +
                "               \"a\":12345,\r\n" +
                "               \"b\":[\r\n" +
                "                  12345,\r\n" +
                "                  12345,\r\n" +
                "                  12345\r\n" +
                "               ]\r\n" +
                "            }\r\n" +
                "         ]\r\n" +
                "      }\r\n" +
                "   ]\r\n" +
                "}";

        String regex = "(\\\"type[A-Z]\\\"):(\\d*)|(\\[.*)|(.*\\])";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
             if(matcher.group().equals("\"typeA\":12345")) {
                 String regex2 = "(\\\"typeA\\\"):(\\d*)";
                 line = line.replaceAll(regex2, "$1:{\"int\":$2}");
             }

             if(matcher.group().equals("\"typeB\":") ) {
                 //I couldn't finish this typeB, because it's too difficult
//                 String regex3 = "(\\\"type[B]\\\"):|(\\s{3}],)";
//                 line = line.replaceAll(regex3, "$1 :{ array: $2 ");
             }
        }
         System.out.println("line: " + line);
    }
}
```

First I used this regex `(\"type[A-Z]\"):(\d*)|(\[.*)|(.*\])`. That regex gives us several groups where we want to look at.

Eventually the while loop encouters `"typeA":12345` 
And that’s where we use the regex `("typeA"):(\d*)`. We use that regex to transfrom `typeA` to:

```
"typeA":{
    "int":12345
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't super fun, due to the names of all the values, but [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) worked just fine.

I pasted json that you wanted into [json2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/):

```
{
  "typeA":{
     "int":12345
  },
  "typeB":{
     "array":[
        {
           "feature":1,
           "value":"1"
        },
        {
           "feature":2,
           "value":"2"
        }
     ]
  },
  "typeC":{
     "array":[
        {
           "a":12345,
           "data":[
              {
                 "a":12345,
                 "b":[
                    12345,
                    12345,
                    12345
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Used the download as zip feature to get the classes to my local development environment.

Then created this monstrosity of a class that tests out Jackson with the generated classes from json2pojo.

```
public class JacksonSerialization {

   public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

       TypeA typeA = new TypeA();
       typeA.setInt(12345);

       TypeB typeB = new TypeB();
       ArrayList<Array> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
       arrays.add(createArray(1, "1"));
       arrays.add(createArray(2, "2"));
       typeB.setArray(arrays);

       TypeC typeC = new TypeC();

       ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
       integers.add(12345);
       integers.add(12345);
       integers.add(12345);

       ArrayList<Datum> data = new ArrayList<>();
       Datum datum = new Datum();
       datum.setA(12345);
       datum.setB(integers);
       data.add(datum);

       Array_ array_ = new Array_();
       array_.setA(12345);
       array_.setData(data);

       ArrayList<Array_> array_s = new ArrayList<>();
       array_s.add(array_);
       typeC.setArray(array_s);

       Example example = new Example();
       example.setTypeA(typeA);
       example.setTypeB(typeB);
       example.setTypeC(typeC);

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, false);
       mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

       ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       //mapper.writeValue(byteArrayOutputStream, example);
       mapper.writeValue(new File("target/Example.json"), example);

       String json = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();

       json = StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(json);

       System.out.println(json);
   }

   private static Array createArray(Integer feature, String value) {

       Array array = new Array();
       array.setFeature(feature);
       array.setValue(value);

       return array;
   }
}
```

Which when this class runs, produces the following json.

```
{
  "typeA" : {
    "int" : 123456
  },
  "typeB" : {
    "array" : [ {
      "feature" : 1,
      "value" : "1"
    }, {
      "feature" : 2,
      "value" : "2"
    } ]
  },
  "typeC" : {
    "array" : [ {
      "a" : 12345,
      "data" : [ {
        "a" : 12345,
        "b" : [ 12345, 12345, 12345 ]
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Which, I think is fairly close to what you asked for.